# Non-vector data and SVM?

Tags: svm, bioinformatics

My research is on antimicrobial peptide classification and prediction. I have gathered peptide sequences of lengths ranging from 10 - 200 and classified them using different machine learning algorithms. The algorithm with the highest performance in terms of ACC, SEN, SPC and MCC was the SVM. My negative and positive datasets are balanced, each with about 500 samples. The total number of attributes was 126. I want to know if my dataset can be classified as a non-vector dataset? Also, if the reason SVM had the best performance is that kernel methods are more appropriate when dealing with non-vector inputs?

P.S. I major in biotechnology and my knowledge on machine learning is very general and basic.

Comment: What do you mean by a non-vector dataset?

Comment: @MarcClaesen Well I don't exactly know what it is but in an article it explained as datasets like sequences and graphs, but I haven't been able to find an exact definition for it.

Comment: Graphs and the like can be summarized as a vector and then dealt with through an appropriate kernel function, so this is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you were able to easily run SVM and other ML models then your dataset is **not** "non-vector like". You had to somehow represent your data in a way that is understandable by SVM and other methods - if you did encode them to vector format then your data **is vector like**. If you, however used some tricky kernel, which fitted model to raw, non vector data (such as text, or graph) you could advocate the term "non-vector like", however this is purely linguistic as "under the hood", SVM always works on vectors, sometimes in a very weird spaces, yet still vector, Hilbert spaces.

Comment: By way of example, OP may be interested in this article on graph kernels. "Diffusion Kernels on Graphs and Other Discrete Structures" http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~risi/papers/diffusion-kernels.pdf

Comment: It's true that kernelized SVMs work in Hilbert space under the hood. But, points in this feature space are not the original data. Rather, they're implicit representations defined by mapping the original data into feature space, as determined by the kernel function. I think it's important to distinguish 1) the fact that data are mapped into a vector space from 2) the data themselves being vectors. (1) doesn't imply (2)

Answer (score 0):

(I just saw this, so if this response is too late, I am sorry.)

Yes, your data is non-vector data.

Since you are able to compute similarities between instances you can cluster them. Once you can cluster them, you can do a number of things (from simplest to more complex):

-Cluster and use centroids for classification: e.g. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4401090/

-Use RBF Networks where the RBF units use your similarity function instead of the regular Gaussians.

-Use SVMs with your similarity measure in the kernels.

...

Hope this helps.

Comment: See also: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320310002463